# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [insserv: warning: script 'mathkernel' missing LSB tags and overrides](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13358/insserv-warning-script-mathkernel-missing-lsb-tags-and-overrides)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Estimated run time off of 9V](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/estimated-run-time-off-of-9v)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Controlling Multiple analog RGB 12V led strips](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13479/controlling-multiple-analog-rgb-12v-led-strips)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Raspberry Pi turned into iBeacon : can't see it on my device (iPhone)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/raspberry-pi-turned-into-ibeacon-bluetooth-le-dongle-not-found-by-iphone-app)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Wi-Pi High Latency](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/wi-pi-high-latency)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the cheapest and long distance (20-30 m) way for communicating Raspberry Pi and attiny (or any other microcontroller)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13215/what-is-the-cheapest-and-long-distance-20-30-m-way-for-communicating-raspberry)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Possible to program an attiny2313 from gpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13514/possible-to-program-an-attiny2313-from-gpio)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Cannot connect to RasPi using static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13524/cannot-connect-to-raspi-using-static-ip)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Data loss (and/or corrupted) over serial USB connection to Arduino](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13280/data-loss-and-or-corrupted-over-serial-usb-connection-to-arduino)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Raspberry PI and TV output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/raspberry-pi-and-tv-output)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Comment: From the vote counts it seems that very few people participated.  A bit sad.

Answer (score 4):

As @Chenmuka pointed out on the other Meta Q by Community, we had a rather poor turn-out on this. On average 8.7 (or 9, if we round up) reviewers.

**That's not even 1 reviewer per question!**

People! This is embarrassing.

I do understand that our user-base is largely beginning programmers and people coming here because they are beginning to learn computers using the Raspberry Pi. Thus, they may be new to the Stack Exchange network and we can't expect them to be involved as we who have been on the network for a while.

**However**, we have enough users to be more involved than 9 people.

We currently have, according to Area 51 for our site, 292 **avid** users (200+ rep), 18 users with 1,000+ rep, and 12 users with 3,000+ rep. You need 350 rep to access the review queue. If we have an average (which is pretty close to the highest of 10 on two of the questions) 9 reviewers per question. **That's only *3%*** if you calculate 9 out of 292.

Of the users on this site, we have, if I did my math correctly, 171 users capable of accessing the basic review queues. If we are only getting **5.25%** of capable users on the site self-evaluation, that's pretty dang bad. And you don't even need review-queue level rep to do the site self-evaluation (I believe, I could be wrong).

I haven't checked up on the other review queues, but I don't think it would be pretty either.

I know that many of the users aren't as active on this site as others, but we really should have more community activity. We also aren't going to have a community that is entirely involved, with reviews and answers. That might result in general chaos, but we could have had a better turn-out for the self-evaluation.

I don't want this to be a *look at how angry RPi Awesomeness can be and look at this attempt to shame people into being better* post; I want it to be an informative, let's see if we can't work this out post that helps the community.

Comment: Eloquently put.  It is also sad that these results only have a couple of dozen views.

Comment: Although, if you think we were bad, look at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/lets-get-critical-mar-2014-site-self-evaluation.  Is there a common thread amongst beta sites for low votes on these evaluations?

Comment: Can someone explain WHY there needs to be a review. There seems to be some kind of high priesthood of Stack Exchange users who are following some secret (at least I don't know what it is) process. For my own part, I am quite happy to answer questions and help others, but am reluctant to criticise others unless what they say is downright wrong - and even then I usually just post a correction.